# Java API to extract content from Flash (swf) file

Tags: java, flash

I am looking for an Java API to extract and control content from an flash (.swf) file. Are there any existing open source APIs which can help me do that?
    Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just googling for info, came across
http://www.anotherbigidea.com/javaswf/

Comment: Hi Sudatta.. Thank you for your reply.. JavaSwf is a very old api.. It doesnt seem to work for the newer versions Java. I get a lot of compile errors which would go if I used an older version of JAVA. But its a perfect API. Something similar is what I am looking at.. Great if you point me to another one.. Thank u :)

Comment: Sorry that was not much help. However, there seems to be a later version(?) of the same at
http://www.stefanocottafavi.com/en/javaswf9

I hope it helps! Also the website has documentation, and looks like its by far the latest.

Comment: If you found the API useful, can you vote up my answer. Not sure if that is the right etiquette for me to ask!

Comment: oops.. sorry Sands.. Its not allowing me to vote up. Says "Vote up requires 15 reputation" :(

Comment: The new link to javaswf9 is http://www.stefanocottafavi.com/?p=50, which source code at https://code.google.com/p/javaswf9/, although it doesn't seem like it does very much.

Answer (score 3):

found this, http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/

> Transform is an Open Source library
>   for reading and writing Flash (.swf)
>   and Flash Video (.flv) files. The API
>   gives you complete control over how
>   files are created with access to all
>   the features supported by the Flash
>   Player but yet is still intuitive and
>   easy to use.